# Enabling iCloud Drive folder for files of an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, icloud

I store files and a persistant core data store in iCloud. If I go to `~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~company~myApp/Documents` I can see the files that are stored in iCloud.

But when I go to the Finder and select iCloud Drive then I can not see the files. If I log onto iCloud.com I can also not see the files.

I have the following entries in my `Info.plist`

```
<dict>
    <key>iCloud~com~company~myApp</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>My App</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>None</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Is there anything else I need to set up for the files and the folder to also show up in Finder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the key is not supposed to reflect the folder name, but instead the namespace so `iCloud~com~company~myApp` is supposed to be `iCloud.com.company.myApp`.